# ASP sessionState not found but timeout less than the default 20 minutes

Tags: asp-classic, sessionstate-timeout

I look around at web.config to find the "sessionState" line to check whether the session timeout is set but I coudn't find any.

As the microsoft said, the default timeout is 20 minutes but the site I am modifying now seems to clear the sessions less than the time given (even less or equal to 5 minutes).

I am a php developer and new to ASP, is there any other place/file that this timeout was set?

I am not sure if I am using ASP or ASP.net, most of the files extension is ASPX so I guess I am using ASP.NET

Comment: asp.net or classic asp? in classic asp session timeout is set in iis configuration or in ANY asp page/global.asa. same for asp.net (iis/web.config/any aspx page)

Comment: @ulluoink, if it is to setup using IIS, is that located at the hosting panel of the site?

Answer (score 0):

for ASP (not ASP.NET) see also

```
Response.Write Session.Timeout '### Read current timeout value
Session.Timeout = 10           '### Set new timeout value
```

> is that located at the hosting panel of the site?

yes, could be. depending on your hosting provider.

NOTE: web.config is for ASP.NET only